# Can a theory play the role of conservatively extending a strictly weaker or incomparable theory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Suppose we have effective first order theories $T, T^+$ and have some injective function $t$ that sends (translate) every formula of the language of $T$ to a formula of the language of $T^+$; such that $T^+$ proves all $t$-translations of theorems of $T$, but $T^+$ doesn't prove $t$-translations of sentences of the language of $T$ that are not theorems nor axioms of $T$.

I'd label that situation as: Theory $T^+$ plays the role of conservatively extending theory $T$ over translation $t$.

> Questions:
>
> 1. Can theory $T^+$ be of incomparable consistency strength with theory $T$?
> 2. Can theory $T^+$ be of strictly stronger consistency strength than theory $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both questions is yes, for unsatisfying reasons.

To avoid immediate triviality we need to require that $t$ (as well as $T$ and $T^+$) be "simple" - say, computable. This is because the sets of $T$-theorems, $T$-non-theorems, $T^+$-theorems, and $T^+$-non-theorems are all countably infinite$^1$ so without a complexity restriction such a $t$ always exists (just pair up a bijection between the $T$-theorems and the $T^+$-theorems with a bijection between the $T$-non-theorems and the $T^+$-non-theorems).

But that still doesn't save us. For example, let's look at $T=PA$ and $T^+=ZFC$. The translation "$\varphi\mapsto\varphi^{HF}$" does not work of course, but there is one which does: send $\varphi$ to (the ZFC-implementation of) the sentence "$PA\vdash \varphi$." This is clearly computable and injective, and assuming ZFC is arithmetically sound we have $$PA\vdash\varphi\quad\iff\quad ZFC\vdash (PA\vdash\varphi).$$ Indeed, this idea works for any pair $T,T^+$ of theories which are appropriately sound and $\Sigma_1$-complete, and that gives very silly positive answers to both your questions.

At the moment I don't see a way to modify the question to avoid this problem.

---

$^1$Saying that a theory is effective presupposes that its language is countable (indeed, effective).

Comment: I think there is a typo, I think you meant: send $\varphi$ to $PA \vdash \varphi$.

Comment: @Zuhair Whoops, quite right - fixed!

Comment: there must be a way to characterize $t$ as to avoid this unsatisfactory condition. I'll think about it. By the way do the above argument work when the theories are incomparable?

Comment: @Zuhair Yes - the only assumption used was that they are both strong enough to talk about provability and that they're both $\Sigma_1$-sound (and complete, but that's basically trivial) in the appropriate ways (e.g. for ZFC, this is meant in the sense of $HF$). For example, it applies to any pair of theories extending (or interpreting, even) the weak arithmetic $I\Sigma_1$.

Comment: @Zuhair I don't know what that means. Any formula $\varphi$ is equivalent to "$T=T$ and $\varphi$" (appropriately phrased). So that restriction seems to rule out *everything*.

Comment: Yes but this would be redundant! I think that $t$ ought to be defined after a parameter free formula that is not equivalent (in $T$ or $T^+$) to a non-redundant formula that mentions $T$ or $ T^+$.

Comment: @Zuhair (1) What precisely does "non-redundant" mean (and for that matter, what precisely does it mean to "mention" a theory - in e.g. the language of arithmetic, everything is a priori just about natural numbers ...)? (2) Even after everything is made precise, can you find *any* example of such a $t$? That's a very strong restriction ...

Comment: non-redundant means cannot be expressed equivalently by a shorter formula. In your example $PA \vdash \varphi$ is equivalent in ZFC to a sentence in which $PA$ occurs (of course in a language that extends the language of ZFC by a primitive constant PA and then run additional axioms to the effect that it is equivalent to PA) and so your formula $PA \vdash \varphi$ in the language of ZFC would be equivalent (in the extended ZFC) to the above formula in the extended language.

Comment: @Zuhair "In your example ⊢ is equivalent in ZFC to a sentence in which  occurs (of course in a language that extends the language of ZFC by a primitive constant PA and then run additional axioms to the effect that it is equivalent to PA)" If you're allowed to change the language, *anything* can be shortened!

Comment: You asked me for an example of $t$ so qualified, I'd think that $\varphi \to \varphi^{HF}$ is an example! (which of course fails)

Comment: No you are only allowed to extend the language as to express theories $T,T^+$ by constants in order to express equivalency to formulas *using them*, so it is not any allowance, its a fixed one. Now the redundancy check can be carried in those particular extended languages as mentioned in the restriction on $t$. Of course the defining formula on $t$ is made in the original languages of theories $T, T^+$, (i.e., not the extended ones).